# How do I convert battery wattage from mAh to Wh?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Airlines allow lithium ion batteries up to 160Wh (https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_US/travel-information/baggage/controlled-and-banned-items/lithium-batteries.html) but portable batteries are sold has having 20000mAh or 30000mAh. How do I convert between these two?

https://www.getbatterybox.com/products/batterybox is rated at 60 Wh / 16,500 mAh. How is 60Wh = 16500mAh?

Thank you.

Comment: W = V * A. Wh = V*Ah, Ah = 1000mAh. Wh = V *mAh/1000.

Comment: mAh is like a marketing term mostly so people will list the highest number that makes some sense. The most common convention is to use the combined capacity of all cells as the listed capacity. Usually the voltage of a cell is 3.7V then times 16.5Ah is roughly 60Wh.

Comment: Also note that this 160 WAh is not a real unit (the page you're referring to calls for 160 Wh).

Answer (score 3):

The first picture on the linked to web site gives the answer:

```
3.7 volts x 1200 milliamp-hours = 4.44 watt-hours
```

or

```
3.7 volts x 1.2 amp-hours = 4.44 watt-hours
```

Comment: That's fine. I'll delete the comment. Next one is SI units named after a person are capitalised when abbreviated and lowercase when spelled out. So, 'V' for volt, 'A' for amp, 'K' for kelvin and, the odd one but still a capital omega, 'Ω' for ohm. I'll fix that for you.

Comment: I knew about capitalizing when named after a person, but didn't know they were lower case when spelled out, thanks.